# How do I modify View.FindResults1 contents in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I need to perform a complex search in Visual Studio: find all occurences of all string identifiers, collect them in "Find Results 1" window and then traverse one-by-one with F4 key.

I wrote a script that generates contents of "Find Results 1":

```
  C:\work\View.cpp(6470):   ON_COMMAND(MENU_USEVIALC_ENABLE, OnUsevialcEnable)
  C:\work\View.cpp(6492):   ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(MENU_USEVIALC_ENABLE, OnUpdateUsevialcEnable)
  C:\work\mainfrm.cpp(1497):               m_wndToolBar.DeleteButton (m_wndToolBar.CommandToIndex (MENU_USEVIALC_ENABLE));
  C:\work\mainfrm.cpp(1502):               m_wndToolBar.DeleteButton (m_wndToolBar.CommandToIndex (MENU_USEVIALC_ENABLE));
```

But how can I paste it into "Find Results 1" window?

I didn't found anything helpful from Visual Studio Command window. 
Probably it is possible using VisualBasic script?

Comment: "But how can I into" - you mean how can you paste it into? I wonder if that's possible, because probably as you noticed also that window is read-only. But maybe the contents can be modified, I haven't ever tried.

Comment: Thanks for noting the typo. Yes, it is Read-Only. But sometimes we have to perform work that needs automatization. I cannot use "Find-In-Files" 600 times, I'd prefer do the search only once, then traverse and do needed code changes.

Answer (score 1):

The `Find Results 1` window is indeed ReadOnly, and it is impossible to do what you want.
You could, however, create your own version of the `Find Results` window by creating a Visual Studio extension yourself. It's actually pretty simple as all the setup work is done by the project templates provided by Visual Studio.

You could start by having a look at [Extending Visual Studio > Tool Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165073.aspx)

Comment: You've given me a hope!

Answer (score 0):

I've found decision for my task:
Call the script from Post-Build process thus having its output in Compile Output window. No additional efforts are needed.
I can even use "Errors" toolbar with warnings, generated by the script.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use Tools->External tools feature:
Title: Process identifiers
Command: C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe
Arguments: $(SolutionDir)\ProcessRcIds.pl $(ProjectDir)
Use output window: Checked (!!!This is the most important option!!!)

This populates Visual Studio window with desired messages